# Intranet faster over the VPN than internal network

Tags: networking, vpn, performance, sharepoint, intranet

We're running a SharePoint 2007 intranet hosted internally.

Whilst sitting at the desk hardwired in the office, browsing/file copying/downloading from the site is acceptable but slow. Pings and Trace routes come back with no extra hops, all under 1ms response times.

If I connect to the standard VPN whilst still in the office and force all traffic over the VPN gateway, speeds of copying files between the Intranet and local machines can almost double.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening to be honest. Any ideas?

Comment: Use [winmtr](http://winmtr.net/) and look for packet loss to those internal destinations while in the office.

Comment: Both internally and externally produce at most 3% traffic loss so no real difference there unfortunately.

Comment: If you try and download a big file from SharePoint internally, does it download quickly?

Comment: Apologies, it was meant to be 0.3% whilst I was testing on a wireless connection. Wired is 0.0%

Answer (score 4):

> Both internally and externally produce at most 3% traffic loss so no real difference there unfortunately

Sustained 3% traffic loss will decimate TCP throughput.  You need to fix that, regardless of whether it's on your internet side or corporate network side.

Speaking as a guy who has built networks for the last 20 years, you should never accept significant ongoing packet loss on a wired network, and do not let any equipment vendor or ISP tell you otherwise.

The most I will tolerate for a public internet service on a cable modem (where you expect some loss from occasional oversubscription) is 0.1% over a 24 hour period, and no more than 0.5% over any 5 minute period.

I tolerate 0.0% packet loss on a wired corporate network.

Wifi is a different game; depending on local conditions, you might not be able to demand good performance from it all the time.  If your corporate wifi is bad enough to complain on serverfault, reengineer that wireless solution to improve performance or get real a wire.

Comment: Well said Mike... there should be ZERO packetloss internally.

Comment: Apologies, it was meant to be 0.3% whilst I was testing on a wireless connection. Wired is 0.0%